# In the html text box, how to show value which itself contains "" symbol?

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to give "" symbol itself in the html text box tag?

My requirement is something like this:

```
<input name="myapi" id="testapi" type="text" value="{"value": "!MYAPI!sdfg" }" class="revapi" hidden="true"/>
```

where `{"value": "!MYAPI!sdfg" }` is the value of the text box

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: This looks like its well answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015380/490188 (How to properly escape quotes inside html attributes?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTML Entities. Here is the example

```
<input type = "text" value = "&quot;{&quot;value&quot;: &quot;!MYAPI!sdfg&quot;}&quot;">
```

Comment: Using single or double quotes. [both are legal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6800482/1577396)

Comment: Mr_Green and Sanjay both of you have given the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap the value with `'` (*single quote*) instead of `"` (*double quotes*)

```
<input name="myapi" id="testapi" type="text" value='{"value": "!MYAPI!sdfg" }' class="revapi"/>
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/szeos8jf/)**

Answer (score 0):

you can escape the "

```
<input name="myapi" id="testapi" type="text" value="{\"value\": \"!MYAPI!sdfg\" }" class="revapi" hidden="true"/>
```

or use ' instead of ""

```
<input name="myapi" id="testapi" type="text" value="{'value': '!MYAPI!sdfg' }" class="revapi" hidden="true"/>
```