# JAXB :Need Namespace Prefix to all the elements inside others

Tags: java, xml, soap, tags, jaxb

jaxb groups all tags in one, I need each tag to have its own namespace.

have:

```
<Request env="DEV" xmlns="http://test1" "xmlns:ns2="urn://test2">
            <ApplicationData>
                <ns2:Application>
                     <Square>test</Square>
                </ns2:Application>
            </ApplicationData>
</Request>
```

need:

```
<Request env="DEV" xmlns="http://test1">
            <ApplicationData>
                <Application xmlns ="urn://test2">
                     <Square>test</Square>
                </Application>
            </ApplicationData>
</Request>
```

adding namespace into @XmlElement  didn't help

```
@XmlElement(
        name = "Application",
        required = true,
        namespace = "urn://test2")
```

package-info:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://test1",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        xmlns = {
            @XmlNs(prefix = "", namespaceURI = "http://test1")
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible with standard jaxbe.
[JAXB Namespace on each xml tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417097/jaxb-namespace-on-each-xml-tag)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and came to the conclusion that it is not solved

Answer (score 0):

Try rebooting ur project, it might help

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).