# Stop unescaping &quot;

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having trouble reading an XML file and adding nodes to it.  Well not exactly.. adding nodes works fine, but the source XML File contains some Lines containing `&quot;`

After Saving my xmlDocument  those `&quot;` parts are converted  to `"`

How can i prevent c# from converting `&quot;` to `"` because the application that loads the xml file needs those `&quot;` marks

Example Line:

`<item name="Description">DBName "xyz"</item>`

Comment: Can you post the code that converts your string to xml?

Comment: Edit:I'm using `XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();  doc.Load(path)  doc.Save(path)` to load and Save my XML Document

Comment: How are you saving your XmlDocument?

Comment: Even if i load the document and save it right after its loaded, the existing `&quot;` parts are converted to `"`

Comment: what is the  application that loads the xml file, and why doesn't it know how to xml correctly?

Comment: XmlDocument is designed to follow the rules for XML. If you're trying to use it with something that doesn't follow the rules for XML, there could be yet more things than this that go wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to encode quotation marks in elements, only in attributes. So:

```
<item name="Description">DBName &quot;xyz&quot;</item>
```

is unnecessary, you can just use:

```
<item name="Description">DBName "xyz"</item>
```

It seems XmlDocument.Load() understands what you mean when you unnecessarily put encoded quotations marks (&quot;) in an element and that by default XmDocument.Save() replaces them with unencoded quotation marks (").

You'll notice exactly the same behaviour if your source is:

```
<item name="Description">DBName &#34;xyz&#34;</item>
```

where " is the XML character reference for "

https://stackoverflow.com/a/150441/283787 explains: *" is not a character that must be encoded in element data.*

If you want to presetve whitespace, simple add the following line of code:

```
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

The consumer of the XML is definitely wrong if it requires to preserve the quote entities in XML texts. By default, the built-in writer replaces the unnecessary entities; however, you can override this behavior by implementing a custom writer:

```
public class PreserveQuotesXmlTextWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    private static readonly string[] quoteEntites = { "&apos;", "&quot;" };
    private static readonly char[] quotes = { '\'', '"' };
    private bool isInsideAttribute;

    public PreserveQuotesXmlTextWriter(string filename) : base(filename, null)
    {            
    }

    public override void WriteStartAttribute(string prefix, string localName, string ns)
    {
        isInsideAttribute = true;
        base.WriteStartAttribute(prefix, localName, ns);
    }

    private void WriteStringWithReplace(string text)
    {
        string[] textSegments = text.Split(quotes);

        if (textSegments.Length > 1)
        {
            for (int pos = -1, i = 0; i < textSegments.Length; ++i)
            {
                base.WriteString(textSegments[i]);
                pos += textSegments[i].Length + 1;

                if (pos != text.Length)
                    base.WriteRaw(text[pos] == quotes[0] ? quoteEntites[0] : quoteEntites[1]);
            }
        }
        else base.WriteString(text);
    }

    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        if (isInsideAttribute)
            base.WriteString(text);
        else
            WriteStringWithReplace(text);
        isInsideAttribute = false;
    }
}
```

You can use it then even from an `XmlDocument` instance:

```
    XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
    xml.Load(filename);
    // ...
    XmlWriter writer = new PreserveQuotesXmlTextWriter(filename);
    xml.Save(writer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,  i really didn't need to escape those quotes. The Problem is that document.save  alters the xml output and so the target application can't properly read the xml.

Example:

`<profile>
 <list name="">
  <item name="FileVersion">0.88</item>
  <item name="ID">xyz</item>`

Turns into

`<profile>
  <list name="">
    <item name="FileVersion">0.88</item>
    <item name="ID">xyz</item>`

There are more spaces before the   node

and if there are empty values

`<item name="Value"></item>`
turns into

`<item name="Value">
          </item>`

Comment: simply set PreserveWhitespace = true. I've updated my original answer to show this.

Comment: PreserveWhitespaces results in a  1 Line output file :(

Comment: Are you setting it before or after your Load?

Comment: I was setting it after i loaded my file.   Setting it before did the trick.  thanks you!

Comment: Great, can you mark my answer as the solution? Thanks.