# Special symbols disappear when using XDocument.Load

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

As I know, there are several symbols in XML, that should be replaced because they are not valid in pure form in xml:

```
< - &lt;
& - &amp;
> - &gt;
" - &quot;
' - &apos;
```

So, I'm trying to load xml document using XDocument.Load(string uri). 
For example I have in my xml document string that looks like this:

```
        <net name="&lt;const0&gt;_1"/>
```

But when my xml is loaded this string is represented in XDocument as

```
        <net name="<const0>_1"/>
```

I've tried to save it using xdocument.Save(string uri), but in result LT and GT symbols wasn't replaced back with & lt; and & gt; it still looks like < and >. Actually when I loaded it again no exception was thrown.
It makes me confused. How could this symbols exist in saved xml file if they are not valid? How can I save my xml file with special symbols replacement? The xml file I'm reading and XDocument I want to save  has a declaration with UTF-8 encoding.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In attributes, `<` and `>` characters are valid, that's why they are not replaced. In Text element they are always entitized:

```
<net>
    <name>&lt;const0&gt;_1</name>
</net>
```

Similarly,  `"` and `'` are allowed as Text element but will be replaced in attributes depending of the enclosing quote type.

> How can I save my xml file with special symbols replacement?

You don't need to care with that. The underlying `XmlWriter` will do the necessary replacements.

Comment: ok, it make a sense for me. But I also have situation like this: <Option Id="COMPARE_VALUE.0" value="eq5'hXX" />
If I understand correctly ' symbol was not replaced with &quot; because it surrounded by " symbols?

Comment: Basically yes, but it depends on the implementation. If you want to force to preserve entities, you can implement a custom writer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32177761/5114784

Answer (score 0):

"Q 3.23: What are the special characters in XML?

```
 Just five: &lt; (<), &amp; (&), &gt; (>), &quot; ("), and &apos; (')."
```

http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html